# Drawing many quads XNA

Tags: xna, optimization

I asked a similar question to this yesterday and gained some knowhow but 
I'm a little confused:

If I have many quads that contain vertices and indices that are positioned to to form a bigger picture, then that bigger picture is positioned using world matrices...

How do I draw them all? From what I've gathered I've got to do in it in one pass for good speed.

I used to draw every quad with its own pass. Now every quad in an object is drawn in one pass.

But if I have a lot of objects it will slow down.

So my question is: how does one go about drawing lots of separate vertices and indices without losing frame rate? I don't need someone to hold my hand just maybe point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Terrain_basics.php . It is about terrains but you should be able to figure out how to combine "quads" (xna doesn't have quads, it is just 2 triangles) in one draw call.